# How to decode a string with gb2312encode to chinese in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, decode

I have a string @"%a9e%b7%cb%ce%d2%a9b%cb%bc%b4%e6",decode online is@"〆匪我゜思存",
how i use OC to decode the string to chinese ?

Comment: can you send me online decoder you used

Comment: `"〆匪我゜思存"` is *not* Chinese because of the first and fourth characters (〆 and ゜).

Those two characters don't even exist in GB 2312: http://www.khngai.com/chinese/charmap/tblgb.php and https://ideone.com/QcQAyg.

Maybe it's [GB 18030](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030) support that you want?

Comment: http://tool.chinaz.com/tools/urlencode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can try with below code.

```
-(NSString *)EncodeGB2312Str:(NSString *)encodeStr {
    CFStringRef nonAlphaNumValidChars = CFSTR("![        DISCUZ_CODE_1        ]’()*+,-./:;=?@_~");
    NSString *preprocessedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)encodeStr, CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingGB_18030_2000));
    NSString *newStr = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,(CFStringRef)preprocessedString,NULL,nonAlphaNumValidChars,kCFStringEncodingGB_18030_2000));
    return newStr; 
}

NSString *string = [self EncodeGB2312Str:@"〆匪我゜思存"];

NSLog(@"string = %@",string); //output is string = %A9%65%B7%CB%CE%D2%20%CB%BC%B4%E6
```